# Pass method as argument without Delegate

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, parameters

Does the C# compiler require a function delegate to pass a function as an argument to another function?

In Visual Basic .Net I can pass a function whose return value is of the same type as a method argument to the method itself without anything fancy. This doesn't appear possible in C# unless the method was written to accept a function delegate??

working vb:

```vb
Function DoSomething(r As DataRow())
        '...
End Function

Function CallSomething()
        Dim dt As DataTable
        DoSomething(dt.Select(""))
End Function
```

C# would require the calling code to assign a variable and pass that, or that the referenced function's signature included a delegate (useful to know). Subtle difference but I was expecting that a simple method call made in one language could be just as easily made in the other since they both compile to the same IL.

here's the C# equivalent I was trying to do:

```cs
string DoSomething(ref DataRow[] r)
{ ///do something }

void CallSomething()
{
    DataTable dt;
    DoSomething(ref dt.Select(""));
}
```

What I meant by "fancy" was the use of delegates, I've used delegates for more complex scenarios, like assigning event handlers to array elements, but I was surprised they would be required for this.

Thanks for the replies. The VB code is functioning as expected, ByRef is implicit in VB, you can't pass an object managed on the heap byval. Nonetheless, here's the simplest form I can provide in VB, if you use a simple forms project w/ a single listbox and drop this code in, should work fine:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim dt As New DataTable("A really great table")
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1", GetType(String))
        dt.Rows.Add("Row1") : dt.Rows.Add("Row2")
        PutRowsInListbox(dt.Select(""))
    End Sub

    Private Function PutRowsInListbox(ByRef r() As DataRow)
        For i As Integer = 0 To r.Length - 1
            Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(r(i).Item("Column1"))
        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: In your VB code, it doesn't look like `r` or `dt.Select("")` are function delegates, they look like values.

Comment: Can you add an example of some C# code that you would expect to work, without doing "anything fancy"?

Comment: I believe you should be able to just do `public void CallSomething() { var dt = new DataTable(); DoSomething(dt.Select(""));}`  And `public void DoSomething(DataRow[] r){}`

Comment: I don't think the VB does what you think it does...

Comment: Your Vb.Net code is not equivalent to your c# code. If you want them to be equivalent, you need to remove the `ref` keyword on the c# code (or add `ByRef` on the VB.Net code).

Comment: That C# has nothing to do with function delegates

Comment: BTW, there are Vb.Net to C# free online converters... here's one of them: https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net/

Answer (score 4):

1. Your Vb.Net code is not equivalent to your c# code. If you want them to be equivalent, you need to remove the `ref` keyword on the c# code (or add `ByRef` on the VB.Net code).
2. Both visual basic and c# allows this style of programming. Please note, however, that you are not passing a function (or method) to another method here, not in Vb nor in c# - you are simply populating the DataRow array with the results of the data table's `Select` method.
3. Since you are not actually passing a method as an argument, a more readable code would be to get the results of the `Select` method into a variable and pass that variable into the `DoSomething` method - but that's more a personal preference thing.
4. The c# code sample you have in the question will not compile.

Here's an equivalent and compilable c# version of the Vb.Net code you have now:

```
void DoSomething(DataRow[] r)
{ 
    //do something 
}

void CallSomething()
{
    DataTable dt = null;
    DoSomething(dt.Select(""));
}
```

Of course, that would throw a `NullReferenceException` unless you actually initialize the `dt` with a value instead of `null`.

BTW, `ByRef` is not implicit. passing reference types does not mean passing them by Reference. That's a common misconception.

When you pass a reference type to a method, what actually is going on is that you are passing the reference itself by value. You can test it easily yourself if you try to reassign the reference inside the method - you'll still see the old value outside the method if you didn't specify ByRef.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - this works. With regards to the ByRef though - that test produces the same results in VB regardless of whether ByRef is specified. I'm not going to pretend I have any idea what the C# 'Ref' does...

Comment: 1. I'm [glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)
2. [Here's a demo that proves ByRef is not implicit in Vb.Net](https://rextester.com/JLV73466)

Comment: @ZoharPeled your demo doesn't tell the full picture. Yes, omitting `ByRef/ByVal` implies `ByVal`, not `ByRef`. But even `ByVal` still gets you the original object, albeit a copy of the reference to it. So you can still modify the original object, but once you modify your copy's reference (i.e. assigning New), you can't. But passing an object `ByVal` is still more like passing a value-type ByRef than ByVal. See [my demo](https://rextester.com/XFL20393)

Comment: Everything is passed by value unless `ByRef` (`ref` in c#) is specified. When passing a value type the value itself gets copied into the argument, and when passing a reference type the reference gets copied into the argument. This means that you have two references pointing to the same instance - and naturally, each one will see what the other has changed. When passing `ByRef`, no new memory gets allocated - but instead, the method use the value that's passed to it. That's why when you're using `ByRef` changes are visible from outside the method. https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @djv sorry, forgot to ping you. Please read the comment above this one.

Comment: @Joe if you use `ref` in C# or `ByRef` in VB with a reference type, you can change the reference in the calling routine to refer to a different object.  With a value type, you can change the value in the calling routine.  In C#, you're also required to denote that this will happen in the calling routine by annotating the function argument with `ref`.  You won't commonly see `ref` in C#, `out` is more common (like `ref` but the language requires to set to the value in the routine).  VB can annotate an argument as `Out` but only has `ByRef` in the language.

Comment: @ZoharPeled with reference types, changes are seen outside the method when using `ByVal`  too. The reference is being passed by value.

Comment: @djv yes, that's correct. As I wrote in my previous comment: "when passing a reference type the reference gets copied into the argument. This means that you have two references pointing to the same instance - and naturally, each one will see what the other has changed."

Comment: @ZoharPeled ok you don't need to explain this to me. I originally wanted to address your demo which doesn't prove anything is implicit (no omitted version of the function is there). I built upon your demo to actually show that it is implicit (at least the behavior is the same). That's all

Comment: @djv I think we're saying the same thing in different words.